# Who exactly is Selim Bradley?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I am currently watching *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*. I have a question regarding the identity of the homunculus inside Selim Bradley.

Is he Pride? Or is he another homunculus?

In [episode 42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fullmetal_Alchemist:_Brotherhood_episodes#Episodes_list), when Van Hohenheim met Pride in an underground passage in Liore, he said that Pride shouldn't have been able to reside outside a spherical body.

This confuses me as to how Selim Bradley can be Pride. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which Full Metal Alchemist are you talking about? 2003 or FMAB 2008?

Comment: my question is regarding FMAB 2008

Comment: When approximately was this comment by Van Hohenheim? (For instance, was this possibly when he was in Lior?)

Comment: @Maroon: I think it's when he went down the underground transmutation circle for the first time. He met Pride for the first time down there, and immediately reminded of the homuculus in the flask in the past, since they have similar characteristics.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Potential spoilers for the manga and Brotherhood continuities. I'm being conservative with spoiler markdown, since I can't tell how much you've watched.

We first get a crucial bit of information after Hawkeye interacts with Selim (ep. 37, vol. 18):

> Selim is indeed Pride. Hawkeye gets suspicious about Selim while talking to Mrs. Bradley and then is confronted by him. Hawkeye later passes on a message to Roy stating that he is a homunculus (vol. 19, can't locate the exact episode number).

Later, the information is confirmed after Edward and the others return to Central (ep. 46-49, vol. 21-23).

> Edward, his brother, his father, and some people who joined him while he was at Briggs fight Selim, who they notice is a homunculus. It is clearly shown that he is Pride: I believe he makes some comment about this, and even if he does not, it is clear from the eye pattern his attack comprises of that he is the same homunculus Van Hohenheim confronted while in Lior (ep. 42, vol. 19).

---

So this leaves your question:

> In episode 42, when Van Hohenheim met Pride in an underground passage in Liore, he said that Pride shouldn't have been able to reside outside a spherical body.

He was referring to Pride being restricted to a specific part of the underground tunnels:

> I assumed that it referred to only the parts of the tunnel that circle Amestris, and the restriction only applied to Pride's real form (not his human container).

It also appears that he was referring to where Pride's shadows could move (at least when he was outside of Central), not where Pride's "container" or body could be:

> After all, Pride is Selim Bradley, and Selim Bradley has a relatively normal-looking life on the surface of Central, where he is probably moving *within* the borders of the underground tunnels.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that when he said that about the shadows it was a case of mistaken identity. He thought it was the imp in the flask but upon closer inspection, realized that he was a different being made to look a lot like the imp in the flask as "an act of vanity"

Answer (score 0):

Selime Bradley is Pride. he is the first Homunculi created by father in Father's image.  he can travel anywhere with in the nation. the transmutational circle acts as a secondary shell